# React Native CameraRoll getPhotos optimization

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

When calling the getPhotos function on the React Native CameraRoll, is there a best practice for how many photos to fetch at once?

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
    first: 10000,
    assetType: 'Photos',
})
```

I want to get every photo off a user's device by creating a while loop until I have every photo. Is it better to fetch more at once, ie 10,000 above, and have less iterations through the while loop, or should I make smaller calls to get 100, 1000, etc photos at a time?

[ReactNative Docs: CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html)

My full code block:

```
async fetchAllImages() {
    let morePhotosToFetch = true;
    let photosAfter = '';
    let photos = [];

    while(morePhotosToFetch) {
        let response = await this.fetchImages(photosAfter);

        morePhotosToFetch = response.morePhotosToFetch;
        photosAfter = response.photosAfter;
        photos = [...photos, ...response.assets];
    }

    return photos;
}

async fetchImages(photosAfter) {
    let { edges, page_info } = await CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        /** SHOULD I FETCH SMALLER BATCHES HERE? */
        first: 10000,
        after: photosAfter === '' ? undefined : photosAfter,
        assetType: 'Photos',
    })

    return {
        assets: edges,
        morePhotosToFetch: page_info.has_next_page,
        photosAfter: page_info.end_cursor,
    }
}
```